# function in normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, function, sympy, normal-distribution, derivative

How to write multiplication function in normal distribution in Python?

I have an error in my code which is as follows, I want to fix this error.

```
TypeError:unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Add' and " NormalDistribution"
```

Comment: your code please?

Comment: How do you possibly expect us to help, without showing the code??

Answer (score 0):

If your question is directly => "How to write multiplication function in normal distribution in Python?"

But, if you ask about your error, you should provide the code (people mentioned in the question comments).

**Sample code for it:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

mu = 0; sigma = 1
sample = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=10) # normal distribution series with numpy
result = sample * 2.0  # multiply with constant 2.0

print(result)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT (after comments):**

I created a sample code for PDF (assumption). I only focus on the multiplication "PDF * (expression)". I neglect the integral part due to the simplification. Maybe if u define it like that, u can express it. It may give u a hint:

**Sample Code for multiplication of the distribution and expression:**

```
import sympy as sp

# symbols
X, K_c, mu, sigma = sp.symbols('X K_c mu sigma')

# probability density function f(K_c)
f_Kc = (1 / (sigma * sp.sqrt(2 * sp.pi))) * sp.exp(-((K_c - mu)**2) / (2 * sigma**2))

expression = (X**2 + 2*X) * f_Kc  # <= multiplication example

# set the derivative equal to zero and solve for X
solutions = sp.solve(expression, X)

# Print the solutions
print("Solutions for X:")
for sol in solutions:
    print(sol)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I want to code the following statement. Kc = Normal and f(kc)=probability function
∫_(Q_o^high)^∞▒〖s_o φ_o Q_o^high+((1+K_h ) α_1-β_1 Q_o^high-γ_1 Q_o^low )(Q_o^high-K_c W_b1 Q_b^cow )f(K_c )dK_c 〗

Comment: your statement cannot be understandable, please refactor your question and showcase it in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Suppose we have a parameter that is random and has a normal distribution (KC). We want to take an integral from an expression, for example (x^2+2x) multiplied by the probability density function of the parameter f(kc). (Integral(x,oo)(x^2+2x)*f(kc)dkc) Then take the derivative of this integral with respect to variable X and set it equal to zero, and the output will be a mathematical formula.

Comment: @HadiGholizadeh  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77297304/edit) your post and add the missing code. Code can be automatically formatted if you add triple backquotes (````) on the lines before and after the code.